# Best way to add column to AbpLanguage and AbpLanguageText?

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I want to add a new column to  Language tables but unlike other models (User, Role,...) I could not find the Language model classes in the solution.
I tried to create a new model (`MyLanguages`) inherited from `ApplicationLanguage` but it is a bad way because I have to do many things. So what is the best way to do it?

Comment: What "many things" do you mean?

Comment: that means I need to re-write the language manager, language repository because, in this way, I have created the new Language table so that all existing methods will not work.

Comment: Existing methods will work fine. What column are you trying to add? You can modify `DefaultLanguagesCreator` and subclass `ApplicationLanguageManager` – that's hard to avoid.

Comment: But they will not work with my new table. I want to add the `HistoryId` to this model (for 4 eyes principle). Every change in this model needs to be reviewed

Comment: Are you sure it actually creates a completely separate table instead of adding a `Discriminator` column?

Comment: Yes, I have marked this question as resolved. Thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no easy way of achieving this issue. like you said, it's not same as User/Role entity. You can create a new entity called MyLanguage and inherit from Language. After that you'll have a Discriminator column. Add a migration to update all existing languages to MyLanguage in discriminator column. Then you have to write custom code to update a new added language to MyLanguage.

https://aspnetzero.com/Documents/Extending-Existing-Entities

Comment: Thanks, I will try it